# How to migrate from Jenkinsfile to pipeline_config.groovy which uses JTE?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-template-engine

I'm in the process of migrating git-based projects to use a shared Pipeline definition from a governance tier built with Jenkins Templating Engine.

In the process of testing I cloned the project and pushed it to a new repository in Bitbucket where it was recognized by Jenkins and the template was used immediately based on the definitions in `pipeline_config.groovy`. However, this is not a sane migration path for existing projects. How do I get Jenkins to start using the template on branches without `Jenkinsfile` and the Jenkinsfile on branches with a Jenkinsfile.

The result of of "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Now" according to the logs is `‘Jenkinsfile’ not found. Skipping`. I assume that a new project regonizer is provided by the Jenkins Templating Plugin.

I assume that every project with Git Flow has to perform this migration, so I'm confused there's no documentation.

I'm using Jenkins 2.306 and JTE plugin 2.3.

Comment: I also asked this question in [JTE gitter channel](https://gitter.im/jenkinsci/templating-engine-plugin), however it makes sense to provide the answer here because gitter is a just a noisy pile of messages.

Comment: I'm using gitlan branch source and jte plugins. Gitlan branch source creates in auto manner jobs (you just need to create a new job with type - gitlab group) for all projects, branches and merge requests in a gitlab group. Also it is possible to configure jte in gitlab group job in jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that newer versions of JTE or Jenkins allow a mixture of branches with JTE and without.

In case you have to deal with versions that don't do the following:

Once I removed `Jenkinsfile` from *every* branch and put a `pipeline_config.groovy` on every branch the Multibranch Plugin started recognizing the project first as removed and at the next scan as present with all branches which were all using the Jenkins Template Engine.

Not the best migration imo, but a great opportunity to cleanup old branches. Since my project was using Git Flow I needed to make a technical hotfix release to also migrate away from Jenkinsfile on `master`.